# Multi-style Nomenclatures

Tags: nomencl

I'm trying to set up a nomenclature page for a report, and have multiple groups where the nomenclature headers I have previously setup don't apply, for example units, symbols etc. This is the script I'm using currently

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\DimensUnits}[2]{\hfill\makebox[12em]{#1\hfill}%
    \makebox[6em]{#2\hfill}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\insertnomheaders}{\item[\bfseries Symbol]%
    \textbf{Description}\DimensUnits{\textbf{Dimensions}}{\textbf{SI Units}}}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\large\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Design Variables}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Terminology}{}}]\insertnomheaders}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\newcommand{\nomdescr}[1]{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\RaggedRight #1}}
\newcommand{\nomwithdim}[5]{\nomenclature[#1]{#2\hfill}{\nomdescr{#3}\DimensUnits{#4}{#5}}}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
    \nomwithdim{A}{\(\Ddot{z_{c}}\)}{Capsule Acceleration}{\si{L.T^{-2}}}{\si{\meter\per\square\second}}
    \nomwithdim{A}{\(\Ddot{z_{h}}\)}{Housing Acceleration}{\si{L.T^{-2}}}{\si{\meter\per\square\second}}
    \nomwithdim{A}{\(\Ddot{z_{in}}(t)\)}{Input Acceleration}{\si{L.T^{-2}}}{\si{\meter\per\square\second}}

    \nomenclature[B]{ISS}{International Space Station}
    \printnomenclature[6em]
\end{document}
```

Doing this prints my nomenclature but also carries the headers with it, I tried moving the

```
\insertnomheaders
```

command to within the definition of group A, this fixed my issue of headers carrying over but introduced another issue where my headers would print over the top of my group title. I have no need for headers in my second group, so if there is a way to limit it only to group A I am all ears

Comment: the example doesn't compile. Neither \Ddot, nor \si, nor \ifstrequal nor \Raggedright are defined.

Comment: Yes that is a problem. Can you please give us a working example?